# format character array in structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
char name[50];
int citNo;
float salary;
} person1;

int main() {
  strcpy(person1.name, "George Orwell");
  person1.citNo = 1984;
  person1. salary = 2500;

  printf("Name: %s\n", person1.name);// it should print Geo

  return 0;
}
```

I want to print only 3 character from name(Geo).Can you please suggest any way to do that.

Comment: Optionally (if you're certain the name has at least 3 characters): `printf("Name: %c%c%c\n", person1.name[0], person1.name[1], person1.name[2]);`

Comment: Use the ["Ask Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button to create a new question. Don't completely edit your previous question and make answers appear out of context. I've rolled back to the original question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to print out only a certain section of a C-string, without making a separate substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780809/is-it-possible-to-print-out-only-a-certain-section-of-a-c-string-without-making)

Answer (score 2):

Use the string format specifier with precision `%.3s`:

```
printf("Name: %.3s\n", person1.name);
```

See also the documentation of *printf*, for instance in Open Group Base specification:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: i have a structure in which there is a char line[20] = "2022/03/13 11:22:33" .. so i have to format this char line as "20220313112233".. so can it be done in any way..                              
  for (int i = 0, j; line[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
      while (!(line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9') && !(line[i] == '\0')) {
         for (j = i; line[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
            line[j] = line[j + 1];
         }
         line[j] = '\0';
      }
   }

Comment: getting segmentation fault error

Comment: @henry: do not ask a new question in a comment box. Use the ["Ask Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button

Comment: i was not able to post questions that why putting in comments section

Comment: @henry You need to create a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom i have edited the question , can you please reply on that?